# Share data between vega-lite graphs

Tags: javascript, html, memory, vega, vega-lite

I have a site with two vega-lite graphs that show different aspects of the same dataset, which is generated dynamically (similar to [this](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/streaming.html) example). Currently they both hold their own version of this dataset.

Since the dataset tends to get quite big I would like them to share the data between them so they  use less memory.

Since the data will be updated later (from the function `update_vega()`) I can't just put it into a variable and embed it in both diagrams.

Is it possible in vega-lite to have multiple graphs sharing the same data-object and how can I do it?

Here is my code (I have only been learning javascript 3 days ago, so I am very happy about feedback on *every* level):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<!-- setup of the vega graph -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.10.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.6.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.3.2"></script>
<div id="vega_graph_one"></div>
<div id="vega_graph_two"></div>
<script>
  var vlSpec_one = {
      $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json',
      data: { name: 'table', values: [{"time":11, "age": 4},{"time":12, "age": 4},{"time":11, "age": 5}]},
      width: 400,
      mark: 'bar',
      encoding: {
          x: {field: 'time', type: 'quantitative', binned: true},
          y: {aggregate: "count", type: 'quantitative'},
          color: {field: 'age', type: 'quantitative'}
      }
  }
  var vlSpec_two = {
      $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json',
      data: { name: 'table', values: [{"time":11, "age": 4},{"time":12, "age": 4},{"time":11, "age": 5}]},
      width: 400,
      mark: 'point',
      encoding: {
          x: {field: 'time', type: 'quantitative'},
          y: {field: 'age', type: 'quantitative'},
      }
  }
  // two global variables so the view can be updated from an outside function
  var view_one;
  var view_two;
  vegaEmbed('#vega_graph_one', vlSpec_one).then(
      result => { view_one = result.view;},
      reason => { console.error(reason);}
  )
  vegaEmbed('#vega_graph_two', vlSpec_two).then(
      result => { view_two = result.view;},
      reason => { console.error(reason);}
  )

  // update the vega graph from outside

  // call with update_vega([{"time":11, "age": 4},{"time":12, "age": 4},{"time":9, "age": 6}])
  function update_vega(event_data){
      var changeSet = vega.changeset()
          .insert(
              event_data
          );
      // data dublication happense here
      view_one.change("table", changeSet).run();
      view_two.change("table", changeSet).run();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use ``concat`` to put the two data views within the same chart specification?

Answer (score 1):

First, consider putting your data in javascript function and call it in data, should be easier to maintain for both data and chart:

```
function getData(){
 var mydata = [{"time":11,"age": 4},{"time":12,"age": 4},{"time":11, "age":5}];

return mydata;
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
{
  "data": getData(),
  "mark": {"type" : "bar"}
}
```

There are several concepts that help achieving data sharing based on your needs.
You need just one `vegaEmbed` and one `vlSpec` that utilizes one of the following:

#### Layers

Put data on top of all layers and refer to it from each mark's layer

```
{
  "data": {"values":getData()},
  "layer": [
   {
     "mark": {"type" : "bar"}
   },
   {
     "mark": {"type" : "point"}
   }
 ]
}
```

#### Concat

`vconcat`, `hconcat`, and `concat` can be used to produce multiple charts of different `mark` each using same data, it doesn't perfectly suite your case because you don't have the same x and y fields in every `mark`. Read more on [Concatenating views](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/concat.html)

```
{
  "data": {"values":getData()},
  "concat": [
   {
     "mark": {"type" : "line"},
     "encoding": {
       "x": {"field": "time"},
       "y": {"field": "age"}
     }
   },
   {
     "mark": {"type" : "bar"},
     "encoding": {
       "x": {"field": "time"},
       "y": {"field": "age"}
     }
   }
 ]
}
```